# Not able to see logs in the index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I have two mutate filters created one to get all the /var/log/messages to type > security and other mutate filter to get all the logs from one kind of hosts to type > host_type.
I am not able to see the /var/log/messages in the host_type index.

Here is the filters code I am using, please help me understand what's going on here. why am I not able to see /var/log/messages in my apihost index?
I have filebeat setup on the hosts to send logs to logstash.

```
filter {
if [source] =~ //var/log/(secure|syslog|auth.log|messages|kern.log)$/ {
mutate {
replace => { "type" => "security" }
}
}
}

filter-apihost.conf
filter {
if (([host.name] =~ /(?i)apihost-/) or ([host] =~ /(?i)apihost-/)) {
mutate {
replace => { "type" => "apihost" }
}
}
}
```

Comment: an escape needs before this. This `//var/log/` needs to be `/\/var\/log\/` . you change this one and see if your code works. Otherwise post here what error you get after changing the regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I fixed the issue by adding clone filter to my logstash config.